# How to clamp a vector within some magnitude?

Tags: python

Given a velocity vector `v = [vx, vy]`, how do we limit the magnitude of `v` such that it is less or equal to some maximum magnitude `maxm`?

i.e. `sqrt(v[0]**2 + v[1]**2) <= maxm`

In order to preserve the direction of the velocity vector, `v[0]` and `v[1]` should be multiplied by the same number.

What Python code would achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Conceptually:

1. Divide by the norm, so you have a vector of unit length.
2. Multiply by the minimum of the original norm and your maximum.

```
In [5]: import math
   ...: def clamp_norm(v, n_max):
   ...:     vx, vy = v
   ...:     n = math.sqrt(vx**2 + vy**2)
   ...:     f = min(n, n_max) / n
   ...:     return [f * vx, f * vy]

In [6]: clamp_norm([0.5, 0.5], 1)
Out[6]: [0.5, 0.5]

In [7]: clamp_norm([0.5, 0.5], 0.5)
Out[7]: [0.35355339059327373, 0.35355339059327373]
```

Comment: `n` is the length of the vector

Answer (score 2):

```
length = sqrt(v[0]**2 + v[1]**2)
if length > maxm:
    multiplier = maxm / length
else:
    multiplier = 1.0
clampedv = [v[0] * multiplier, v[1] * multiplier]
```